# What is the meaning of the strength of the sun lamp?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting

all other lamp types in blender uses a physical unit to define strength but the sun lamp has a unit less strength value.So what is the unit of the sun lamp strength if it has or if it is relative what does 1 strength mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html#sun-light):

> Strength of the lights in Watts per square meter.

Though, I'm wondering if that should be kilowatts instead of watts.

Comment: That's a good observation. Sun intensity on a clear day is roughly 1000 W/m^2.